# Pandas to_excel from SQL query outputs a memory address

Tags: python, pandas

I am attempting to output the results of a SQL query to a database as an Excel file.

What appear to be UUID values are not outputting as strings properly, and I'm not sure how to get Pandas to output these as a hexadecimal string representation.

```py
df = pd.read_sql(query,conn) 
writer = pd.ExcelWriter(output_filename, engine='xlsxwriter')
df.to_excel(writer,"data")
```

Output of example value:
`<memory at 0x00000204FC8C7AC0>`

I attempted this:

`df["GUID_LCXX"] = df["GUID_LCXX"].astype(str)`

But the output was the same.

How can I get pandas to output the string hex value representation of the UUID and not a memory reference?

Comment: A UUID isn't a string, it's a 128-bit value. If you use `uuid`, the value is an in-memory object wrapping the 128-bit value. You can't just cast it to a string. There are multiple ways UUIDs can be represented as strings. Which one do you want?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos A hex value representation

Answer (score 0):

Solved this myself, posting here for future searchers and in case someone wants to propose a more efficient/elegant solution.

```py
guid_columns = ["GUID_LX1", "GUID_LX2"]
for col in guid_columns:
    df[col] = df[col].apply(lambda x: (x.tobytes().hex()).upper())
```

Comment: You could use `str(x)` instead. From [the uuid module docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/uuid.html): `str(uuid) returns a string in the form 12345678-1234-5678-1234-567812345678 where the 32 hexadecimal digits represent the UUID.`